# how install language in flutter tts plugin

Tags: android, flutter, text-to-speech

I am facing a problem in converting text to voice. The reason is that some Android devices do not have the language available, such as Indonesian or Turkish, and he must download it on his device in order to speak the text.

How can I load the language programmatically through flutter tts plugin ?

thank you

this is my tried

flutterTts
?.isLanguageInstalled("tr_Tr")
.then((value) => value = (value as bool));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await flutterTts.setLanguage("tr-TR");
  await flutterTts.setVoice({
    "name": "tr-tr-*isim*",
    "locale": "tr-TR",
  });
```